# Trying to modify WordPress plugin action contained in a class

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the WooCommerce bookings plugin and I am trying to modify the following action:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', array( $this, 'includes' ) );
```

This is contained in the construct function of the WC_Bookings class full code of which can be found here http://pastebin.com/4WqkTpge

Following the WordPress reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action I am calling it through a variable that holds the class instance, in this case

> $GLOBALS['wc_bookings']

The code I am using is as follows:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'includes' );

    function includes() {



                remove_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', array( $GLOBALS['wc_bookings'], 'includes' ) );
        }
```

This code is contained within a custom plugin.

Many thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Try including $priority parameter in the remove_action, alternatively call your includes() function later in time(different hook). Other than that, the code seems to be fine.

Comment: Thank you, the original add_action didnt include the $priority parameter so I dont think this is to be included?

Comment: Ok, then you can try with a different action to hook your function.